# i need to start setInterval when i submit a form using onsubmit

Tags: forms, setinterval, onsubmit

hi am trying to make setinterval work when i submit a form,

this what i have so far

```
setInterval(function(){ getUsers(); }, 1000);


`document.getElementById("cal").onsubmit = 
function getUsers()
{
$.ajax({
url: 'test.php',
type: 'post',
success: function(data) {
  $('.htmlelement').html(data);
}
});
}'
```

html

```
<FORM id= "cal" NAME="Calc" action="seller.php" method="post" 
onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how intervals should be wrapped. What you should do is wrap the submit button inside an interval and then make it call your function. You can use this `fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/wauzpzdz/1/ for this purpose.